# Testing HTTP/2 using `openssl s_client`

Tags: bash, http, https, openssl

CloudFlare’s blog post on [tools for debugging, testing and using HTTP/2](https://blog.cloudflare.com/tools-for-debugging-testing-and-using-http-2/) mentions this approach to finding out which protocols are supported by a given server:

```
$ openssl s_client -connect www.cloudflare.com:443 -nextprotoneg ''
CONNECTED(00000003)
Protocols advertised by server: h2, spdy/3.1, http/1.1
```

This approach seems to work fine for many domains I’ve tested. However, the (HTTP/2-enabled) domain `benchmarkjs.com` produces output that looks completely different, and I don’t know why:

```
$ openssl s_client -connect benchmarkjs.com:443 -nextprotoneg ''
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=0 C = US, ST = Washington, L = Seattle, O = Odin, OU = Plesk, CN = Plesk, emailAddress = info@plesk.com
verify error:num=18:self signed certificate
verify return:1
depth=0 C = US, ST = Washington, L = Seattle, O = Odin, OU = Plesk, CN = Plesk, emailAddress = info@plesk.com
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/C=US/ST=Washington/L=Seattle/O=Odin/OU=Plesk/CN=Plesk/emailAddress=info@plesk.com
   i:/C=US/ST=Washington/L=Seattle/O=Odin/OU=Plesk/CN=Plesk/emailAddress=info@plesk.com
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=/C=US/ST=Washington/L=Seattle/O=Odin/OU=Plesk/CN=Plesk/emailAddress=info@plesk.com
issuer=/C=US/ST=Washington/L=Seattle/O=Odin/OU=Plesk/CN=Plesk/emailAddress=info@plesk.com
---
No client certificate CA names sent
Peer signing digest: SHA512
Server Temp Key: ECDH, P-256, 256 bits
---
SSL handshake has read 1409 bytes and written 448 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
    Session-ID: C0474D42297C21B374C558E698A69EEBBFF537B35E6365D31B4D7AA2CD4192AD
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Master-Key: 2292DF581DAE3CE4A4E8CFF5A351A3F4E99602A7DCDBD090998C38926498743B4E3A808A1C4505136D51FC847F0153A6
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1455103745
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 18 (self signed certificate)
---
```

Note that it doesn’t return to the prompt; you’re connected to the server and can now enter e.g. `GET / HTTP/1.1` followed by `Host: benchmarkjs.com`.

So, my two questions are:

1. What’s different about `benchmarkjs.com` that makes this technique not work?
2. Is it possible to use `openssl s_client` to detect HTTP/2 support in a generic way that works even for this domain?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My take: the `openssl s_client`'s manual states:

> -nextprotoneg protocols
>
> enable Next Protocol Negotiation TLS *extension* and provide a list of comma-
>   separated protocol names that the client should advertise support for. The
>   list should contain most wanted protocols first.  Protocol names are
>   printable ASCII strings, for example "http/1.1" or "spdy/3".  Empty list of
>   protocols is treated specially and will cause the client to advertise
>   support for the TLS extension but disconnect just after reciving ServerHello
>   with a list of server supported protocols.

(Emphasis mine.)

So I'd say the SSL/TLS engine terminating your request at `benchmarkjs.com` merely does not support that Next Protocol Negotiation extension or has it disabled for some reason.  Hence in your test the `openssl s_client` command advertises that is supports NPN but the server turns a blind eye onto ot.
The handshake still passes OK because the extension appears to be non-essential (or at least considered to be such by `openssl`) and you get the connected TLS tunnel.

As to implementing reliable checking, I'm afraid since `openssl s_client` apparently does not have any command-line option which would force it terminate the session immediately, you would have to go a level deeper and write your own program linking to `libssl` which would implement the desired behaviour. (And I would personally implement it in [Go](http://golang.org) using the [`crypto/tls`](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/tls/) package of its standard library as it's no harder to program than JavaScript but produces a statically-linked program meaning no-brainer deploys.)

Comment: [See is-http2 issue #10](https://github.com/stefanjudis/is-http2/issues/10#issuecomment-182586175): “Next Protocol Negotation” is not available in Apache 2.4.x, which is what benchmarkjs.com is using. It has appeared in 2.5.0, according to [the Apache httpd trunk CHANGES](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpd/httpd/trunk/CHANGES). TL;DR It’s possible to support HTTP/2 using Apache 2.4.17 and later but the abovementioned `openssl s_client` command won’t detect it.

Comment: Redirecting stdin from /dev/null should make s_client terminate the session immediately (i.e. `openssl s_client ... </dev/null`).

Comment: @MathiasBynens, a heads-up: [the recent statement from the Chrome team](http://blog.chromium.org/2016/02/transitioning-from-spdy-to-http2.html) says that NPN is obsolete in favour of ALPN.